# How to get the userId from the current session?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a log-in, a registration and a reservation page. When people registrate, then log-in and then make a reservation, I want to get the userId (which is the name for the Id in my mysql database) from the logged-in person. I've been told that it's like this:

```
$_SESSION["userId"]
```

When I do this it gives me an error saying undefined index: userId
Someone told me to put the userId in the Session, but i have no idea how because I'm still a beginner. I've tried to google it but with no success.

```
var_dump["$_SESSION"]
```

Gives me:
Registration page = `array(0) { }`
Log-in page = `array(0) { }`
reservation page = `array(1) { ["loggedIn"]=> bool(true) }`

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=store+data+in+php+session&ia=qa does any of this help? Your question seems to be "how to store x in a session"...

Comment: "I've tried to google it but with no success" What does that mean? There are _millions_ of examples and documentations to be found on google.

Comment: I'm sure that there are good examples on google. But as I said, I'm not an expert in PHP. I just want to get the userId from my database table 'users' and whenever a user makes a reservation I want to get that userId and put it into my database table 'reservations' together with the reservation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put your code as `$_SESSION["userId"] = $userID;` where $userID is the data getting from post or get method

Comment: If i could I would send you flowers!